Inconsistent inception scores for DCGAN with same data and noise
I've been working on training a DCGAN on the CIFAR-10 dataset, and I'm evaluating the quality of generated images using the inception score. However, I've noticed that the Inception Scores vary significantly even when using the same data, without reshuffling, and identical noise vectors.
Is this variability natural, or am I possibly doing something wrong in my implementation?
Here's the relevant part of my code:
# import os
# os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
# import tensorflow as tf
# tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)

import argparse
import os
import random
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.parallel
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.utils.data
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision.utils as vutils
import numpy as np
from inception_score import inception_score
from termcolor import colored,cprint

from utils import get_gaussian_filter, get_gaussian_filter_2

# Set random seed for reproducibility
manualSeed = 1
random.seed(manualSeed)
torch.manual_seed(manualSeed)

# Number of workers for dataloader
workers = 1

# Batch size during training
batch_size = 128

# Spatial size of training images. All images will be resized to this size using a transformer.
image_size = 64

# Number of channels in the training images. For color images this is 3
nc = 3

# Size of z latent vector (i.e. size of generator input)
nz = 10

# Size of feature maps in generator
ngf = 64

# Size of feature maps in discriminator
ndf = 64

# Number of training epochs
num_epochs = 2

# Learning rate for optimizers
lr = 0.0002

# Beta1 hyperparameter for Adam optimizers
beta1 = 0.5

# Number of GPUs available. Use 0 for CPU mode.
ngpu = 1

# Load the dataset
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(64),
    transforms.CenterCrop(64),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
])

dataset = dset.CIFAR10(root='./data', download=True, transform=transform)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

total_size = len(dataset)

# Decide which device we want to run on
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if (torch.cuda.is_available() and ngpu > 0) else "cpu")

# custom weights initialization called on ``netG`` and ``netD``
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)

# Generator Code
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.std = 1
        self.mean1 = 1
        self.kernel_size = 3

        self.convtrans1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(nz, ngf * 8, 4, 1, 0, bias=False)
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU(True)
        self.convtrans2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU(True)
        self.convtrans3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False)
        self.batchnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU(True)
        self.convtrans4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False)
        self.batchnorm4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU(True)
        self.convtrans5 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False)
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()

    def forward(self, input):
        x1 = self.convtrans1(input)
        x1 = self.batchnorm1(x1)
        x1 = self.relu1(x1)
        x2 = self.convtrans2(x1)
        x2 = self.batchnorm2(x2)
        x2 = self.relu2(x2)
        x3 = self.convtrans3(x2)
        x3 = self.batchnorm3(x3)
        x3 = self.relu3(x3)
        x4 = self.convtrans4(x3)
        x4 = self.batchnorm4(x4)
        x4 = self.relu4(x4)
        x5 = self.convtrans5(x4)
        x5 = self.tanh(x5)
        return x5

netG = Generator(ngpu).to(device)
if (device.type == 'cuda') and (ngpu > 1):
    netG = nn.DataParallel(netG, list(range(ngpu)))
netG.apply(weights_init)

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.std = 1
        self.mean1 = 1
        self.kernel_size = 3

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(nc, ndf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False)
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf)
        self.leakyrelu1 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(ndf, ndf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2)
        self.leakyrelu2 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(ndf * 2, ndf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False)
        self.batchnorm3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 4)
        self.leakyrelu3 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(ndf * 4, ndf * 8, 4, 2, 1, bias=False)
        self.batchnorm4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 8)
        self.leakyrelu4 = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, input):
        x1 = self.conv1(input)
        x1 = self.batchnorm1(x1)
        x1 = self.leakyrelu1(x1)
        x2 = self.conv2(x1)
        x2 = self.batchnorm2(x2)
        x2 = self.leakyrelu2(x2)
        x3 = self.conv3(x2)
        x3 = self.batchnorm3(x3)
        x3 = self.leakyrelu3(x3)
        x4 = self.conv4(x3)
        x4 = self.batchnorm4(x4)
        x4 = self.leakyrelu4(x4)
        x5 = self.conv5(x4)
        x5 = self.sigmoid(x5)
        return x5

netD = Discriminator(ngpu).to(device)
if (device.type == 'cuda') and (ngpu > 1):
    netD = nn.DataParallel(netD, list(range(ngpu)))
netD.apply(weights_init)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
fixed_noise = torch.randn(64, nz, 1, 1, device=device)
real_label = 1.
fake_label = 0.
optimizerD = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))
optimizerG = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))

# Training Loop
img_list = []
G_losses = []
D_losses = []
iters = 0

filename = "/content/drive/My Drive/DCGAN/dcgan cifar10 results 13 basic.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
noise_list = torch.load("/content/drive/My Drive/DCGAN/noise_list.pt")
j = 0

print("Starting Training Loop...")
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
        netD.zero_grad()
        real_cpu = data[0].to(device)
        b_size = real_cpu.size(0)
        label = torch.full((b_size,), real_label, dtype=torch.float, device=device)
        output = netD(real_cpu).view(-1)
        errD_real = criterion(output, label)
        errD_real.backward()
        D_x = output.mean().item()

        noise = noise_list[j].to(device)
        noise = noise[:b_size]
        fake = netG(noise)
        label.fill_(fake_label)
        output = netD(fake.detach()).view(-1)
        errD_fake = criterion(output, label)
        errD_fake.backward()
        D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        optimizerD.step()

        netG.zero_grad()
        label.fill_(real_label)
        output = netD(fake).view(-1)
        errG = criterion(output, label)
        errG.backward()
        D_G_z2 = output.mean().item()
        optimizerG.step()

        if i % 50 == 0:
            print('[%d/%d][%d/%d]\tLoss_D: %.4f\tLoss_G: %.4f\tD(x): %.4f\tD(G(z)): %.4f / %.4f' %
                  (epoch, num_epochs, i, len(dataloader), errD.item(), errG.item(), D_x, D_G_z1, D_G_z2))

        G_losses.append(errG.item())
        D_losses.append(errD.item())
        iters += 1

        is_score, is_std = inception_score(fake, cuda=True, batch_size=32, resize=True, splits=10)
        f.write(f"{epoch},{is_score}, {is_std}\n")

f.close()

Inception Score Calculation:
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn import functional as F
import torch.utils.data
from torchvision.models.inception import inception_v3
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import entropy
import math

class IgnoreLabelDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, orig):
        self.orig = orig

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.orig[index][0]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.orig)

def inception_score(imgs, cuda=True, batch_size=32, resize=False, splits=1):
    """Computes the inception score of the generated images imgs
    imgs -- Torch dataset of (3xHxW) numpy images normalized in the range [-1, 1]
    cuda -- whether or not to run on GPU
    batch_size -- batch size for feeding into Inception v3
    splits -- number of splits
    """
    N = len(imgs)
    if batch_size > N: batch_size = N
    assert batch_size > 0
    assert N >= batch_size
    if cuda:
        dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor
    else:
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            print("WARNING: You have a CUDA device, so you should probably set cuda=True")
        dtype = torch.FloatTensor

    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(imgs, batch_size=batch_size)
    inception_model = inception_v3(pretrained=True, transform_input=False).type(dtype)
    inception_model.eval()
    up = nn.Upsample(size=(299, 299), mode='bilinear').type(dtype)
    
    def get_pred(x):
        if resize:
            x = up(x)
        x = inception_model(x)
        return F.softmax(x).data.cpu().numpy()

    preds = np.zeros((N, 1000))
    for i, batch in enumerate(dataloader, 0):
        batch = batch.type(dtype)
        batchv = Variable(batch)
        batch_size_i = batch.size()[0]
        preds[i * batch_size:i * batch_size + batch_size_i] = get_pred(batchv)

    split_scores = []
    for k in range(splits):
        part = preds[k * (N // splits): (k + 1) * (N // splits), :]
        py = np.mean(part, axis=0)
        scores = []
        for i in range(part.shape[0]):
            pyx = part[i, :]
            scores.append(entropy(pyx, py))
        split_scores.append(np.exp(np.mean(scores)))

    return np.mean(split_scores), np.std(split_scores)

Observations:

The random seed is set for reproducibility.
I'm loading pre-saved noise vectors from a file to ensure consistency.
The Inception Score is calculated within the training loop.

Despite these measures, the Inception Score varies between runs. How can I determine if this variability is expected, or if there's something wrong with my approach?
